# CFStreamCreateBoundPair can not free

Tags: ios, swift, instruments, core-foundation, cfstream

I use `CFStreamCreateBoundPair` to create a pair of stream in order to upload a large file.The code is like below.

```
let readStreamPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?>.alloc(1)
let writeStreamPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?>.alloc(1)
let bufferSize = 1024*1024 //1M buffer size
CFStreamCreateBoundPair(kCFAllocatorDefault, readStreamPointer,writeStreamPointer, Int(bufferSize) as CFIndex)
if let rStream = readStreamPointer.memory?.takeRetainedValue(),writeStream = writeStreamPointer.memory?.takeRetainedValue() {

}
```

Everything goes well except a memory issue.I check out with Instruments and find out `CFStreamCreateBoundPair` can not free the memory of buffer size which in this case is 1M after both the `CFReadStream` and `CFWriteStream` are closed.I have a screen shot too.

[image: Instruments screen shot]
I am not quite familiar with Core Foundation framework in swift and don't know why it can not be auto released.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I do it:

```
class func createBound(inputStream: inout InputStream?, outputStream: inout OutputStream?, bufferSize: UInt) {
    var readStream: Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
    var writeStream: Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?
    CFStreamCreateBoundPair(nil, &readStream, &writeStream, CFIndex(bufferSize))
    if inputStream != nil {
        inputStream = readStream!.takeUnretainedValue()
    }
    if outputStream != nil {
        outputStream = writeStream!.takeUnretainedValue()
    }
}
```